# Is the following logic of simplifying the complicated expression correct?

Tags: integration

Assume 
I have three variables $s, \omega,\gamma$ and define a function $G(.)$.

Next consider the following function

\begin{align}
\prod_{{i>1}}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Bigg(\frac{1}{1+s  G(\omega_i)\gamma_{i}^{-1} }\Bigg)\ d\omega_i\right)\\\nonumber
\end{align}

Notie that $\omega_i$ and $\gamma_i$ are both indexed by $i$.

Is it true that I can re-write the above as

\begin{align}
\prod_{{i>1}}h(\gamma_i,s) \\\nonumber
\end{align}

where

$$h(\gamma_i,s)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Bigg(\frac{1}{1+s  G(\omega_i)\gamma_{i}^{-1} }\biggl) \ d\omega_i$$

It is the indexing under the $\prod$ that is confusing me, since both the integrand has index $i$ and the product outside too, is my logic correct?

Comment: What is $f_{\Omega_i(\omega_i)}$?

Comment: sorry typo i fixed it

Comment: The integrand is also, and especially, a function of $\omega_i$. Your function $h$ should be $h(\gamma_i,s,\omega_i)$, or something similar.

Comment: but we have integrated over $\omega_i $ marginalized over it why would $h$ be a function of it

Comment: Although the notation is ambiguous, having a product over $i$ would imply that $\omega_i$ might depend on $i$ one way or another.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe it should be made clear what $\gamma_i$ and $\omega_i$ are, e.g. they are different possible values of $\gamma$ and $\omega$ (or components maybe)? In any case what you suggest here is simply writing the complicated-looking integral expression as a function with two parameters $s$ and $\gamma_i$. There are two possible explanations: either $\omega_i$'s are arbitrary dummy variables and the author wanted to emphasize that these are different integrals, or $\forall i$: $\gamma_i$ and $\omega_i$ are related, for instance componentwise. Depending on the context, it might disable you to first add the terms and then integrate.